# Twig, variable inside javascripts block

Tags: twig, block

```
{% set url = '@ApiBundle/Resources/public/js/themes/'~theme~'.js' %}

{%javascripts 
    '@ApiBundle/Resources/public/js/highcharts-3d.js'
     {{url}}

%}

<script src="{{asset_url}}"></script>

{%endjavascripts%}
```

I have the following code that gives an error, how can I make it work?

Comment: You still need to follow the syntactical rules.  On your js, you need to assign {{url}} to a variable.

Comment: That will not work. Assetic works way before a request is handled (and you can assign value to the theme var. Simply put that single js in a regular script tag.